# sticky right hand menu preselect on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im sure this is an easy question.
We're trying to create a sticky right hand menu. We are currently using bootstrap.

This is easy enough by using affix to stick the menu.

How ever, what we are struggling to work out, is when scrolling down the page, the appropriate menu item is is highlighted.

Plenty of examples of what we are trying to achieve on the web :-
http://getbootstrap.com/css/   (see right hand menu)
http://www.facebook.com   (on the time line view, the year changes when scrolling)

any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is called Scrollspy. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Answered by Christina Arasmo Beymer in the comments

"That is called Scrollspy. getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy"